# Spark Cassandra Issue with KeySpace Replication

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

> **I have created table in Cassandra with below commands:**

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 
'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 3 } AND DURABLE_WRITES = false;  

use test;

create table demo(id int primary key, name text);
```

> **Once the table got created successfully, I was running the below code to write the data into Cassandra from Spark.
>
>    *But facing below error***

Code Snippet of Spark

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql._

val connectorToClusterOne = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","xx.xx.xx.xx").set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "xxxxxxx").set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "xxxxxxx"))

---K/V---
val data = sc.textFile("/home/ubuntu/test.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => demo(p(0).toInt,p(1)))

implicit val c = connectorToClusterOne
data.saveToCassandra("test","demo")
```

**BELOW IS THE ERROR DESCRIPTION:** .

*Error while computing token map for keyspace test with datacenter dc1: could not achieve replication factor 3 (found 0 replicas only), check your keyspace replication settings.*

**Could any one suggest what could be the possible reason for this.**

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually because either the request is not being directed at the correct cluster or the datacenter does not exist or has an incorrect name.

To make sure you are connecting to the correct cluster double check the connection host used for your spark application.

To check the datacenter, use `nodetool status` to make sure that the datacenter which you requested exists and includes no extraneous whitespace.

Lastly, it could be possible that all the nodes in the datacenter are down, so double check this as well.

Comment: I ran nodetool status , below is the outcome of the same.

```Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 81.19 KiB  256          67.1%             e0156fb8-e2a9-42fd-b691-ec545bf3f9d4  rack1
UN  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  79.61 KiB  256          66.3%             b6467692-8894-4c4e-879b-4fcb2ac8b749  rack1
UN  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   88.94 KiB  256          66.6%             9b7d86c8-8526-4053-9380-10a9be897811  rack1```

Comment: This is a case of the datacenter being wrong. Your datacenter is not named `dc1` it is named `datacenter1`. Since there is no datacenter `dc1` there will never be available replicas in `dc1`